# What are the best practices of sharing the user id among microservices?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security

I have two Spring Boot microservices deployed as of now:

1. Auth Gateway
2. Restful services with business logic.

Auth Gateway issues a jwt token after the successful login. For the next request, it validates/authorizes the jwt token before redirecting the request to the business logic.

What is the best way to share user related information from Auth Gateway to other services?

Between `Auth Gateway` is written using SpringSecurity and Spring Boot.

Comment: Encode all necessary details (user id etc.) in the JWT token

Comment: @StanislavL You mean, update the jwt token with the user id etc after login?

Answer (score 4):

Encode all necessary details (user id etc.) in the JWT token.

You issue the token in the Auth Gateway and JWT Access token has three parts: Header, Claims and Signature

Place all the necessary info into the claims section. See [the example](http://www.svlada.com/jwt-token-authentication-with-spring-boot/)

```
@Component
public class JwtTokenFactory {  
    private final JwtSettings settings;

    @Autowired
    public JwtTokenFactory(JwtSettings settings) {
        this.settings = settings;
    }

    /**
     * Factory method for issuing new JWT Tokens.
     * 
     * @param username
     * @param roles
     * @return
     */
    public AccessJwtToken createAccessJwtToken(UserContext userContext) {
        if (StringUtils.isBlank(userContext.getUsername())) 
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Cannot create JWT Token without username");

        if (userContext.getAuthorities() == null || userContext.getAuthorities().isEmpty()) 
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("User doesn't have any privileges");

        Claims claims = Jwts.claims().setSubject(userContext.getUsername());
        claims.put("scopes", userContext.getAuthorities().stream().map(s -> s.toString()).collect(Collectors.toList()));

        DateTime currentTime = new DateTime();

        String token = Jwts.builder()
          .setClaims(claims)
          .setIssuer(settings.getTokenIssuer())
          .setIssuedAt(currentTime.toDate())
          .setExpiration(currentTime.plusMinutes(settings.getTokenExpirationTime()).toDate())
          .signWith(SignatureAlgorithm.HS512, settings.getTokenSigningKey())
        .compact();

        return new AccessJwtToken(token, claims);
    }
```